# Array.IndexOf for 2 matching values c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that stores some information.

I search this array to match the first column using this code:

```
int i = Array.IndexOf(ARRAY, ARRAY.Where(x => x.Contains(VALUE)).FirstOrDefault());
```

But what I want to do is find the index that matches the first value and second value.

Something like this (if that makes sense):

```
int i = Array.IndexOf(ARRAY, ARRAY.Where(x => x.Contains(VALUE1)).FirstOrDefault() && Contains(VALUE2)).Second());
```

Edit on request:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //get states
    Console.WriteLine("state1");
    string state1 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("state2");
    string state2 = Console.ReadLine();

    //read from csv
    String[] statearray = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test\States.csv");
    var query = from line in statearray
                let data = line.Split(',')
                select new
                {
                    Start = data[0],
                    Finish = data[1],
                    StatesCrossed = data[2],
                };

    //get index
    int i = Array.IndexOf(statearray, statearray.Where(x => x.Contains(state1)).FirstOrDefault());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Where `state 1` and `state 2 ="NSW"`
and where `csv` is in the format:

```
NSW, NSW, 1
NSW, VIC, 2
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output please? It would help clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code

```
int index = query.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i + 1 })
                 .Where(p => p.Value.Start == state1 && p.Value.Finish == state2)
                 .Select(p => p.Index)
                 .FirstOrDefault() - 1;
```

But you also need to trim your elements:

```
var query = from line in statearray
            let data = line.Split(',')
            select new
            {
                Start = data[0].Trim(),
                Finish = data[1].Trim(),
                StatesCrossed = data[2].Trim(),
            };
```